# Using haml partial to loop through and display

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Using Haml and Sinatra, given an array, what is the best way to use a partial to show each element?

For example, if I define a helper:

```
#controller.rb
helpers do
  def showAllLines()
    @multipleLines.each { |l|
      @partialvar = l
      haml :partialview, :layout => false }
  end
end
```

... this basically calls the partial view over and over, which is not what I want. I'd really rather have each partial result appended to another view, which is using the `showAllLines()` helper:

```
-# index.haml
=showAllLines
```

How do I get each element of `@multipleLines` to show in `index.haml`, using a helper and partial view?

Comment: please be gentle, i'm learning! any links to help me better understand Sinatra with Haml would be appreciated.

Comment: Aaron, I'm not clear what your question is. The way you're looping and rendering a partial is pretty much exactly how you'd go about doing this. What do you mean by "rather have each partial result appended to another view"? Looping through and rendering partial for each element essentially appends the output to your main view (`index.haml`). Can you clarify?

Comment: The fact that you are learning is great, but it does not provide an unlimited excuse to state questions poorly. Please specify what you want to achieve, what you have tried and why the result you got is unsatisfactory. Partials are intended to be used exactly as you’ve described and it’s hard to understand why you are looking for something else and, specifically, _why would you look for smth else_.

Comment: A good place to start might be http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials (Section 3.4.5) this should work with haml as well. So you could put something like render `:partial_view, multipleLines` straight into your haml file

Comment: may be useful - keep in mind though that rails != sinatra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the loop in haml. This is why I like haml compared with erb. It doesn't look like crap to put a bit of programming in the view.

```
-# index.haml
- @multipleLines.each do |oneLine|
  .oneLine
    = oneLine.someData
    = oneLine.someOtherData
```

Also I would prefer to pass `multipleLines` in as a local to the view instead of having an instance variable. It makes your code more solid. If you still want to have one line in its own partial you can call `render :partial` something from inside the loop in `index.haml`.